# how to prove finite set of natural number A has a largest number by contradiction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I start with an contradiction statement that let A be the finite set of natural number that has no largest number. And let $M =\{m\in\mathbb N\mid n \in m,\forall a \in A,\, n>a\}$

And since no natural number is larger than itself $M$ must not contains $A$.

Now the next step i should do is to prove that $M = \mathbb N$ by induction to drive the contradiction I desire. (That is, the contradiction statement that let $A$ be the finite set of natural number that has no largest number false for all natural number.)

But i false to show that $M$ contains $1$. because it seems to me that $A$ do contains $1$ in this case. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: I don't get why you need to prove $M=\mathbb N$.

Comment: Maybe you want to show $|M| = |\Bbb{N}|$, i.e., that $M$ is not finite?...

Comment: since M does not includes A by showing M=N seems to drive the contradiction that A has no largest number is false for all natural number which shows A has an largest number for all natural numbers

Comment: @ Eric Towers
my problem here is not know how to show that M contains 1 to use induction rules to show that |M|=|N| :(

Comment: Why do you need M?  You have A, a finite set of natural numbers.

Comment: What is your definition of finite? Without a definition to USE, you can do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not to proove $M=\mathbb N$. Because if $A\ne\emptyset$, then there exists $a$ as an element of $A$, and $a\notin M$.

I'll use another variation of $M$ you used, as $L=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid\forall a\in A, a\le n\}$. Then $L$ is not an empty set, because $A$ is finite, so $\sum_{a\in A}a=x\in L$.

And by well-orderness of $(\mathbb N, \le)$, every non-empty subset of $\mathbb N$ has their minimal element. I'll let $\min L=m$.

Then $\forall a\in A, a\le m$. And if $m\notin A$, then $\forall a\in A, a< m$ holds. This mean $\forall a\in A, a\le m-1$. So $m-1\in L$. This contradicts with minimality of $m$. So $m\in A$.

So, $m$ is the maximal element of $A$(what means, $m$ is the largest number of $A$).

Comment: thank you so much! not just for helping answer but also edit my question!!!

Comment: but im still a little unclear about how is showing  m is the maximal element of A makes contradiction statement that A is the finite set of natural number that has no largest number false?

Comment: nvm i undertand now , thank you again